# Is there a way to get another dog?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I managed to buy a dog from a guy outside Markarth and it followed me everywhere, just as I was told. Alas, my furry friend fell in battle.

I assumed I would be able to buy another dog, just as you do with horses, but I went back and no more doggies. Is there anyway for me to get another dog or have I lost my four-legged companion for good?

Comment: I had a dog once, but then he took an arrow to the knee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appear to be only [two companion dogs](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dog) in the game:

- Meeko - you can find this dog in [Meeko's Shack](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Meeko%27s_Shack)
- Vigilance - who is the dog [you've described](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vigilance_%28dog%29).

Commenters point out that there's a [stray dog](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Stray_Dog) you can find, and that during a Daedric quest you will temporarily gain an "essential" (and therefore unkillable) [dog follower](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Barbas), which you can keep as long as you don't finish the [related quest](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/A_Daedra%27s_Best_Friend).

You can only have one at a time, and when they're gone, that's it for dogs.

Comment: There's also Barbas. If you're uninterested in the rewards from [A Daedra's Best Friend](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Daedra%27s_Best_Friend), Barbas is an immortal companion dog.

Comment: This is close, but you've missed the [stray dog](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stray_Dog).

Comment: Important note about Barbas:  You can't keep him if you want to complete the Oblivion Walker achievement.

Answer (score 5):

Ya, like dags? Dags?

The answer is yes, you can get more dogs:

- [Meeko](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Meeko) - One only. Lame
- [Vigilance](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vigilance) - One only. Lame
- [Barbas](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Barbas) - One only. Super awesome, invincible dog (but also annoying)
- [Stray dogs](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stray_Dog) - These can be found in the wild multiple times but they're pretty lame.

Comment: What the hell is a googy?

Comment: ... Seriously? 
http://cheezburger.com/Squirts_Mommy/lolz/View/1770738944
http://cheezburger.com/View/4070722816
http://cheezburger.com/maxie/lolz/View/1978070272

But I'll change it for the memeless...

Comment: Wow, tough crowd. Yes, that was a joke.

Answer (score 0):

The same exact thing happened to me. You need to go back to the Markarth stables and there is a door to the stables near the horses. You need to pick the lock and there is a staircase going down into a room. In the room should be Vigilence. You need to talk to him and tell him to follow you. Then you will probably be confronted by guards. Pay the bounty and then you will spawn neer the calstle in Markarth and Vigilence should be with you. What happens is when you make your dog wait for more than 2 in-game days your dog wanders back to the stables. If you have kids and a house you can walk inside and your kid will ask you if they can keep your dog (the kid might not ask for the dog the first time so keep trying) say yes except for when I'm using him. Then you can tell him to go home and he will stay at your house as a pet.

Comment: You wont get arrested if you attempt to pick a lock undetected.